# polynomial of $x$?

Tags: terminology

I want to refer to functions of the form $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^{\alpha_i}$ where $\alpha_i < 1$.

This is not a polynomial, because $\alpha_i$ could be just real arbitrary numbers (though positive ones).
Is there a name for this class of functions that I can refer to? Wikipedia does claim these are not polynomials.

Comment: I want to change the name of this thread since polynomials by definition have only nonnegative integer powers of the variable, but I can't think of a better title... :(

Comment: @J.M.: "linear combinations of real powers of $x$"?

Comment: I stated it as a question... so perhaps it is okay. "is it a polynomial of $x$?"

Comment: Is $\alpha<1$ a typo for $\alpha>0$ or $\alpha\geq 0$?

Answer (score 3):

In 1983 they still had no official name, see for example [this paper](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P16.pdf) by Peter Borwein.

Comment: Thanks. From the title of the paper, don't you think it is called "polynomial with variable exponents?"

Comment: (though, it seems like this name was rarely used, according to google.)

Answer (score 1):

Such a function is called "sum of power functions". I don't know of any shorter name. If $\alpha_i<1$ is not a typo, then it's a sum of power functions with exponents less than $1$.